# On repeat translations to the same recursion, do you always use the same foci?

Tags: cypher-system, the-strange

In *The Strange* RPG, you can change your focus whenever you translate. One thing that isn't clear to me is if you always should use the same focus on repeat visits to a given recursion. For example, if you travel to Ardeyn, can you have Abides in Stone the first time you visit, and then Works Miracles another time?

If you can choose, suppose you return to your native recursion (or Earth). Can you have a different focus then? That seems weird. It means that people may change professions or even species when you see them on different occasions.

Related: I am already aware that, if you have a draggable focus, you can choose to drag it, or not, on each trip (if I'm reading the book correctly). So there is some precedent for changing your focuses on different visits, but again, some odd things can happen if you extend this too far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page 20 in the corebook states

> Once you’ve selected a focus for a particular recursion, it doesn’t change

Contrariwise, as Caleb points out, a sidebar in page 55 offers

> Each time you return to a recursion, your GM might offer you the choice of picking a focus that’s different from one you had last time you visited.

As for draggable foci, page 52 states

> Some foci are draggable. This means that if you start with a focus in its proper context, you can keep it when you translate to another world. You’re “dragging” your focus with you. If you have a draggable focus but decide to change your focus when you translate, you cannot regain the draggable focus again unless you return to the original world to which it is tied. From there, you can drag it again if you wish.

Which is not for or against reassigning a focus.

So, those are the RAW, and the suggestion for houseruling. Apart from bookkeeping, I don't see a problem with doing it.

Comment: Okay, missed that. Although, two counter examples:
1. The draggable focus contradicts this statement.
2.  I just saw on page 55 in the sidebar that "your GM might offer you the choice of picking a focus that's different than the one you had last time you visited [the same recursion]."

Comment: I've incorporated this in my answer.

Comment: Page 360 says: "The next time
the PCs visit that recursion, they can choose a
different look and focus if they want."

Comment: @Oxinabox That's an optional rule, and the context of that sentence is important. The suggestion is that *if your players don't know the recursion*, you just give them some focus on their first visit, and the next time -- assuming they have gotten a feel for the place by then -- they get to choose their "real" and final focus.